# How to extract the name of the DB and place it on an annual bar chart?

Tags: php, laravel, charts

I was asked to make a graph where I should extract the names, along with the amount it has per year.

The way I did it was just to bring the total and the year for each portal name.

```php
$portalInmobiliario = Ticket::selectRaw('year(created_at) as anio, count(id) as total')
                            ->where('source_id', 1)
                            ->groupBy('anio')
                            ->get();

$tocToc = Ticket::selectRaw('year(created_at) as anio, count(id) as total')
                ->where('source_id', 2)
                ->groupBy('anio')
                ->get();

$enlaceInmobiliario = Ticket::selectRaw('year(created_at) as anio, count(id) as total')
                            ->where('source_id', 3)
                            ->groupBy('anio')
                            ->get();

$webBI = Ticket::selectRaw('year(created_at) as anio, count(id) as total')
               ->where('source_id', 4)
               ->groupBy('anio')
               ->get();

$_portal = [];
foreach ($portalInmobiliario as $pi) {
    $_portal[$pi->anio] = $pi->total;
}

$_toc = [];
foreach ($tocToc as $toct) {
    $_toc[$toct->anio] = $toct->total;
}

$_enlace = [];
foreach ($enlaceInmobiliario as $inmobiliario) {
    $_enlace[$inmobiliario->anio] = $inmobiliario->total;
}

$_web = [];
foreach ($webBI as $webbi) {
    $_web[$webbi->anio] = $webbi->total;
}

$years = [];
$dataToc = [];
$dataPort = [];
$dataEnlace = [];
$dataWeb = [];
$currentYear = date('Y');

for ($i = $currentYear; $i > $currentYear - 5; $i--) { 
    $years[] = $i;
    $dataPort[] = isset($_portal[$i]) ? $_portal[$i] : 0;
    $dataToc[] = isset($_toc[$i]) ? $_toc[$i] : 0;
    $dataEnlace[] = isset($_enlace[$i]) ? $_enlace[$i] : 0;
    $dataWeb[] = isset($_web[$i]) ? $_web[$i] : 0;
}
```

My HTML y Script

```xml
<div class="row row-eq-height mt-2">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
        <div class="iq-card">
            <div class="iq-card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
                <div class="iq-header-title">
                    <h4 class="card-title text-center">Graph</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="iq-card-body">
                <div id="chartGeneral"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    const year = <?php echo json_encode($years)?>;
    const portal = <?php echo json_encode($dataPort)?>;
    const toctoc = <?php echo json_encode($dataToc)?>;
    const enlace = <?php echo json_encode($dataEnlace)?>;
    const bi = <?php echo json_encode($dataWeb)?>;

    var optionsGeneral = {
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Portal Inmobiliario',
                data: portal
            },
            {
                name: 'TOC TOC',
                data: toctoc
            },
            {
                name: 'Enlace Inmobiliario',
                data: enlace
            },
            {
                name: 'Web B-I',
                data: bi
            }
        ],
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            height: 350,
            stacked: true,
            stackType: '100%'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                horizontal: true,
            },
        },
        stroke: {
            width: 1,
            colors: ['#fff']
        },
        /*title: {
            text: 'Fiction Books Sales'
        },*/
        xaxis: {
           categories: year,
            labels: {
                formatter: function (val) {
                   return val
                }
            }
        },
        yaxis: {
            title: {
                text: undefined
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            y: {
                formatter: function (val) {
                    return val
                }
            }
        },
        fill: {
            opacity: 1
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
            horizontalAlign: 'left',
            offsetX: 40
        }
    };
    
    var chartGeneral = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chartGeneral"), optionsGeneral);
    chartGeneral.render();
</script>
```

Although this is how the code works, they asked me to extract the names from the DB, but I couldn't find a way to join the years and the total for each portal.

[image]

Comment: Where are the names stored? `Source` model?

Comment: Yeah Source but when I do all the process of extracting the quantities by source and grouping them by year at the time of passing it to the graph does not work or I get the last one only and that I put it in arrangements and in json format.

Example in the DB I have 5 fonts, then of those 5 fonts I make a join with contacts and I see how many come from this source and in what year they were registered the total. @IGP

Comment: Can you edit your question and add information about the Ticket and Source tables?